# How to return only alphanumeric substring?

Tags: regex, swift3, swift4

I'm new to Swift Programming. I would like to ask if anyone can help me to return only alphanumeric substring from a string ?

Example:

> Input = "wolf & lion"
>   Output = "wolflion"

I wonder if there is any solution besides regex.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
let outputStr = "wolf & lion".components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)
                .joined()
print(outputStr)//wolflion
```

Comment: Thank you ! This answer is working. And with the least line of code

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "abs1  2csd^!@awerqwe"
let b =  a.characters.map { (char) -> String in
    if let charRange = String(char).rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.alphanumerics) {
        return String(char)
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}.joined()

//OR use unicode scalar
let c = a.unicodeScalars.map { (char) -> String in
    if CharacterSet.alphanumerics.contains(char) {
        return String(char)
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}.joined()
```

Output: `abs12csdawerqwe`

Answer (score 0):

Please check :

```
let str = "wolf & lion"
let charset = str.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics)
let alphanumericString = str.components(separatedBy: charset).joined(separator: "")
print(alphanumericString) // wolflion
```